# Is there a function for identifying the location of these circled parts of a signal waveform

Tags: signals, signal-processing, waveform, originlab

It might be called the "foot" or "leading edge" but I don't think that's fully correct.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blHuK.png)

I've tried the 1st and 2nd derivative but the peaks are slightly off of this location.

Answer (score 0):

Those circled points are quick (maybe even discontinuous?) increases in the function's derivative. I'd try to locate them by identifying points where both

- the first derivative is positive, and
- the second derivative is large and positive

using some [finite difference approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) to estimate the derivatives.